# How to use the bluebird concurrency option for the map function

Tags: concurrency, promise, bluebird

I am trying to use bluebird's map function with the built-in concurrency control.

I want to retrieve a list of names, then make a number of POST requests for each name. For example, I want to make a request for each name for each day of the week. However, I need to throttle the number of concurrent POST requests because the intended server has rate limits.

```
function getNames() {
    //Open mongodb connection
    //Get collection and array of names
    //return array of names in a promise 
}

function createDatesArray() {
    //Create an array of rates
    //return array of dates in a promise
    //Ex. return Promise.resolve(datesArray);
}

getNames().map(function (name) {
    return createDatesArray().map(function (date) {
        return requestData(date, name);
    }, {concurrency: 5});
}).then(function () {
//do something
});
```

Is this the correct way to use bluebird's concurrency?

The documentation link is here [bluebird documentation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Short answer: **yes** , this will limit the number of requests to 5.

Caveat: keep in mind you might still be susceptible to more limits, such as the HTTP client's, or any other pools, modules and services you might be using.

Also, a Mongo connection is meant to be used as a persistent one, so you should probably only open one and then use it rather than open and close one every time.

If `createDatesArray` does not do anything asynchronous, you do not have to Promise.resolve it, you can instead use the static variant of `map` as `Promise.map(datesArray, function(date){ ... })` etc. I would also not nest. Assuming `createDatesArray` is indeed async:

```
Promise.join(getNames(), createDatesArray(), function(names, dates){
    var tasks = [];
    names.forEach(function(name ){ // create Cartesian product of names * dates
        dates.forEach(function(date){
             tasks.push(function(){ return requestData(name, date); });
        });
    });
    return Promise.map(tasks, function(job){ return job(); } , { concurrency: 5} );
}), then(function(results){
     // do whatever
});
```

Comment: Sweet. I was doing Promise.using on the mongo connection elsewhere. I didn't know the static variant of the map took the concurrency option as well. Your code example is a very readable approach. TY.