# React/Redux State is empty on second action call

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm still relatively new to React/Redux so apologies if this is a simple question but I am yet to find a solution.

I have an two actions:

```
// DESTINATIONS
// ==============================================

export const DESTINATION_REQUEST = 'DESTINATION_REQUEST';
export const DESTINATION_SUCCESS = 'DESTINATION_SUCCESS';
export const DESTINATION_FAILURE = 'DESTINATION_FAILURE';

export function loadDestination (params, query) {

    const state = params.state ? `/${params.state}` : '';
    const region = params.region ? `/${params.region}` : '';
    const area = params.area ? `/${params.area}` : '';

    return (dispatch) => {
        return api('location', {url: `/accommodation${state}${region}${area}`}).then((response) => {
            const destination = formatDestinationData(response);

            dispatch({
                type: DESTINATION_SUCCESS,
                destination
            });
        });
    };
}





// PROPERTIES
// ==============================================

export const PROPERTIES_REQUEST = 'PROPERTIES_REQUEST';
export const PROPERTIES_SUCCESS = 'PROPERTIES_SUCCESS';
export const PROPERTIES_FAILURE = 'PROPERTIES_FAILURE';

export function loadProperties (params, query, rows = 24) {

    return (dispatch, getState) => {

        console.log(getState());

        return api('search', {locationId: xxxxxx, rows: rows}).then((response) => {
            const properties = response.results.map(formatPropertiesData);

            dispatch({
                type: PROPERTIES_SUCCESS,
                properties
            });
        });
    };
}
```

these are combined with their relative reducers:

```
// DESTINATIONS REDUCERS
// ==============================================

export default function destination (state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
    case DESTINATION_SUCCESS:
        return action.destination;
    default:
        return state;
    }
}





// PROPERTIES REDUCERS
// ==============================================

export default function properties (state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
    case PROPERTIES_SUCCESS:
        return action.properties;
    default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

and they are called from within a component (connectDataFetchers loops through the called actions and returns them to the component for server side rendering):

```js
// PROPTYPES
// ==============================================

Search.propTypes = {
    destination: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    properties: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};





// ACTIONS
// ==============================================

function mapStateToProps ({destination, properties}) {
    return {destination, properties};
}





// CONNECT & EXPORT
// ==============================================

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(
    connectDataFetchers(Search, [loadDestination, loadProperties])
);
```

```js
export default function connectDataFetchers (Component, actionCreators) {
    return class DataFetchersWrapper extends React.Component {
        static propTypes = {
            dispatch: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
            location: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
            params: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
        };
        
        static fetchData (dispatch, params = {}, query = {}) {
            return Promise.all(
                actionCreators.map((actionCreator) => dispatch(actionCreator(params, query)))
            );
        }

        componentDidMount () {
            DataFetchersWrapper.fetchData(
                this.props.dispatch,
                this.props.params,
                this.props.location.query
            );
        }

        render () {
            return (
                <Component {...this.props} />
            );
        }
    };
}
```

I need to run the first action (loadDestination) which will return an ID then needs to then pass to the second action to load properties with that location ID.

If I hardcode a locationID this works fine, but if I try to access the state in `loadProperties` via `getState()` then it returns `{ destination: [], properties: [] }`.

Is there a way to access the value from the first action via the state?

## SOLUTION

Managed to get this to work following the suggestion from @pierrepinard_2

I created a new action that dispatches the two other actions in the order I needed:

```js
// SEARCH
// ==============================================

export function loadSearch (params, query) {
    
    return (dispatch) => {
        return dispatch(
            loadDestination(params, query)
        ).then(() => {
            return dispatch(
                loadProperties(params, query)
            )
        })
    }
}

// DESTINATIONS
// ==============================================

export const DESTINATION_REQUEST = 'DESTINATION_REQUEST';
export const DESTINATION_SUCCESS = 'DESTINATION_SUCCESS';
export const DESTINATION_FAILURE = 'DESTINATION_FAILURE';

export function loadDestination (params, query) {

    const state = params.state ? `/${params.state}` : '';
    const region = params.region ? `/${params.region}` : '';
    const area = params.area ? `/${params.area}` : '';

    return (dispatch) => {
        return api('location', {url: `/accommodation${state}${region}${area}`}).then((response) => {
            const destination = formatDestinationData(response);
            
            dispatch({
                type: DESTINATION_SUCCESS,
                destination
            });
        });
    };
}
  
  // PROPERTIES
// ==============================================

export const PROPERTIES_REQUEST = 'PROPERTIES_REQUEST';
export const PROPERTIES_SUCCESS = 'PROPERTIES_SUCCESS';
export const PROPERTIES_FAILURE = 'PROPERTIES_FAILURE';

export function loadProperties (params, query, rows = 24) {

    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        return api('search', {locationId: getState().destination.id, rows: rows}).then((response) => {
            const properties = response.results.map(formatPropertiesData);

            dispatch({
                type: PROPERTIES_SUCCESS,
                properties
            });
        });
    };
}
```

then in the component I just request the one action:

```js
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(
    connectDataFetchers(Search, [loadSearch])
);
```

Comment: Could you share how <Search> calls loadDestination & loadProperties?

Comment: @DamienLeroux - I've added some more code from the search component plus the `connectDataFetchers` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use Promise.all() in your fetchData() method: your actions are dispatched in parallel, not one after another.

To ensure that you call first destination then properties, you should create one specific async action creator for your Search component. This async action creator would implement the successive requests you need in this case.

Comment: I tried that initially calling the two functions within a seperate function but that didn't attach to the respective variables in the mapStateToProps. How do I maintain that relationship?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The mapStateToProps() function retrieves your props from the one and only state of your app. Is it a problem with the order in which the api requests are received? If you use redux-thunk middleware to handle your async requests and want to chain dispatch() calls with then(), be sure to always return the promises in your async action creators (more info in https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#composition). For example, you should "return dispatch(...);" in your action creators.

Comment: Thanks @pierrepinard_2 - following the redux-thunk suggestion I got this to work and have added the solution above

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @pierrepinard_2.

Using [promise.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) from bluebird, you should be able to call all given promise syncronously.

This [post on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745455/how-to-use-the-bluebird-concurrency-option-for-the-map-function) should help you on that matter.

Let us know if it works